# JSF / PrimeFaces: Navigate from one tab to another

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

Using Primefaces tab view (`<p:tabView>`), how to navigate from one tab to another tab?

For example:

```
<p:tabView id="tabPanel">
  <p:tab id="tab1">
       <p>Tab 1</p>
       <a href="#">Go to tab2</a2>
  </p:tab>
   <p:tab id="tab2">
       <p>Tab 2</p>
  </p:tab>   
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use client side scripting api of PrimeFaces. Define a `widgetVar` attribute in `tabView`. Then use `select(index)` client side api.

```
<p:tabView id="tabPanel" widgetVar="tabPanelWidget">
  <p:tab id="tab1">
       <p>Tab 1</p>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeTab(1);">Go to Tab2</a2>
  </p:tab>
   <p:tab id="tab2">
       <p>Tab 2</p>
  </p:tab>   
</p:tabView>
```

Be carefull about the parameter to JS function. the index of tab , which is zero based, is passed to Javascript.

here is client side code

```
function changeTab(index)
{
    tabPanelWidget.select(index);
}
```

**tabView with Dynamic Content**

Furthermore, if you have dynamic content you can simulate the client side api as user click the tab.

I go deep into source code of the component. A tabview component consist of a div and unordered list items which include a `<a>` tags to click. Then i select that `<a>` tags from the page and clicked with jquery.

See my jquery code:

```
function changeTab(tabId)
    {
       $('#formId\\:tabPanel ul li a[href="#form:tabPanel:"+tabId+"]').click();
}
```

Here is the details of selectors.

**#formId\:tabPanel :** `formId` is the id of the page. If `prependId="false"` is used this part can be skipped. `\\` is escape for `:` and tabPanel is the id of the tabview.

**ul li :** is unordered list items which represents tabs.

**a[href="#form:tabPanel:"+tabId+"]' :** `<a>` tag whose href attribure is equals to tabId.

Furthermore, i inspect the source code from PrimeFaces showcase. It may be have some differences in your codes.

Comment: yes, I already tested in this way. It works, but after redirecting the contents of `tab2` displayed empty. In normal clicking it shows fine. could you tell is there any issue?

Comment: Are the tabs have dynamic content?

Comment: Yes. In `tab2` i populate the records in dataTable. So that, i setted `<p:tabView id="tabPanel" widgetVar="tabPanelWidget" dynamic="true">`

Comment: @Ranjith please see my edits. I posted some client side code for dynamic contents.

Comment: My upvote assumes your review please of the typos with correction offered as formatted answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `activeIndex` attribute of `p:tabView`. You have to store it in a variable and then modify it using an action.

```
<p:tabView id="tabPanel" activeIndex="#{myBean.activeIndex}">
    <p:tab id="tab1">
        ...
        <p:commandLink action="#{myBean.goToTab(2)}">Go to Tab2</p>
    </p>
    <p:tab id="tab2">
        ...
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

MyBean:

```
 public class MyBean {
     private int activeIndex;
     public void goToTab(int index) {
         this.activeIndex = index;
     }
 }
```

Comment: There is no need to add additional property to the managed bean. client side api of primefaces is better to use.

Comment: That would be needed if you want to save the tab state between different pages.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your TAB of Your tabview having this :

```
    <p:tabView id="tabProyecto"  widgetVar="tabPanelWidget" cache="false">
....
```

In any buttom you can call the jquery function "changeTabs"

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {


            });

            var changeTabs= function (index) {
                 PF("tabPanelWidget").select(index);
            };
            ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are typos in the answer by @erecan above, the form for dynamic tabs should be:

```
function changeTabDynamic(tabId)
{
   $('#formId\\:tabPanel ul li a[href="#formId:tabPanel:'+tabId+'"]').click();
}
```

*Provided as answer not comment for clear formatting*

Answer (score 0):

Important:

Maybe you have to add `$(document).ready(function()`, because the JavaScript runs before the page load.

```
function changeTabDynamic(tabId) {
    $(document).ready(function() {$('#tabViewId ul li a[href=\"#tabViewId\\: + tabId + \"]').click()})");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In fact you need to put:

```
function changeTab(index) {
    tabPanelWidget.selectTab(index);
}
```

and not:

```
tabPanelWidget.select(index);
```