# PrimeFaces tabview: tabs are not selected properly

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I tried to implement the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350475/jsf-navigate-one-tab-to-another-tab-in-primefaces) but it doesn't work.These are the steps to reproduce the problem:

- Program shows first tab selected
- User clicks on the second tab
- Javascript code selects first tab with

  ```
  tabViewVar.select(0)
  ```

where tabViewVar is defined in

```
 <p:tabView id="tab1" widgetVar="tabViewVar">
```

The result is that the first tab is selected, however the objects of the second tab are still shown (not hidden).

An ideas?

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of detail. At what point are you calling `select`? What version of primefaces are you running?

Comment: My application has a div that contains the TabView. The div is hidden, and the user clicks on a button to display it. When the div and its contained TabView are displayed, the program needs to show the first tab in the TabView, so it performs `tabView.select(0)`. If it doesn't do the select, when the TabView is shown after the div is hidden, it would show the last selected tab.


I'm using PrimeFaces version 3.5

Comment: I just tested with PF 4.0 and have the same problem.

Comment: `select` only **SELECTS** tabs, it doesn't deselect them. You need to unselect them: `PF('tabViewVar').unselect(1); PF('tabViewVar').select(0);`

Comment: @rion18 Thanks for your input. when I do `PF('tabViewVar').unselect(1);` I get a javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Tested with PF 5.0.

Comment: I'm sorry I confused accordionPanel and tabView, it seems two answers somehow got mixed up. However, `widgetVar.select(index)` should work. Testing again on the showcase website, it seems the problem comes from putting the tabView inside a div. Is there another container that is appropriate for the objective you want?